# impulse and Lagrange equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Why is it that  $$\int_t ^{t+\epsilon t} \frac {\partial L}{\partial q_i} dt =0$$  for impulsive force but not this: $$\int _t^{t+\epsilon}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} = finite$$
Source :[Lagrange equation for impulsive forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326887/lagrange-equation-for-impulsive-forces)

Comment: Can we get more information about the context in which you encountered these equations? For example for a harmonic oscillator Lagrangian one would expect that both would be finite and proportional to $\epsilon.$

Comment: There was this problem that $\int Fdt$ was finite for an infinitesimal time interval.  Then it was needed to show how the Lagrange equation can be stated in such case.

Comment: @CR Drost : This was the problem: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326887/